# slick slider изменить значение сдвига слайда

Tags: slider, slick.js

Как в  slick slider изменить значение ширины сдвига слайда.

Answer (score 1):

```
variableWidth: true
```

Убирает ширину заданную slick-oм

Answer (score 0):

Имеется ввиду на сколько изображений будет сдвигаться слайдер? Попробуйте:

```
$('.class').slick({
    slidesToScroll: 3 // установить необходимое число
});
```